# Boolean Variables and If statement fails for true statements

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean-logic

Here's the prompt:

> Clunker Motors Inc. is recalling all vehicles in its *Extravagant* line from model years 1999 – 2002. Given variables `modelYear` and `modelName` write a statement that assigns `True` to `recalled` if the values of `modelYear` and `modelName` match the recall details and assigns `False` otherwise.

I wrote this code but kept getting wrong answers for the true statements. The false statements came through just fine.

```
modelYear >= 1999 and modelYear <= 2002
modelName == "Extravagant"
if modelYear == True and modelName == True:
    recalled = True
else:
    recalled = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do -

```
modelYear >= 1999 and modelYear <= 2002
modelName == "Extravagant"
```

You are just throwing away the result of those boolean expressions, this does not magically make `modelYear` or `modelName` boolean values.

Instead of trying to create boolean values, you can simply use the expression in the `if` block itself. Example -

```
if 1999 <= modelYear <= 2002 and modelName == "Extravagant":
    recalled = True
else:
    recalled = False
```

---

And if inside the `if` block in your real code, all you do is assign the boolean value, then you can do -

```
recalled = 1999 <= modelYear <= 2002 and modelName == "Extravagant"
```

Comment: Bingo! The single line did the job! Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

When you have:

```
modelYear >= 1999 and modelYear <= 2002
modelName == "Extravagant"
```

You don't store the result of the statements. To make it work you could something like:

```
year = modelYear >= 1999 and modelYear <= 2002
name = modelName == "Extravagant"
if year and name:
    recalled = True
else:
    recalled = False
```

But the easier solution would be to do it directly in the `if` statement like:

```
if modelYear >= 1999 and modelYear <= 2002 and modelName == "Extravagant":
    recalled = True
else:
    recalled = False
```

The shortest way of doing it would be:

`recalled = modelYear >= 1999 and modelYear <= 2002 and modelName == "Extravagant"`

Comment: Did not see the one above... Oops.