# How to put both an int variable and String Variable inside .equals() that matches with a Boolean variable?

Tags: java

I am new to Java.

How to put the `int` variable of `int year = 1999` and the `String` variable of `String name = "Tai"` together inside `name.equals();` so that `boolean r` gets `true` if the `int` and `String` values match `boolean r` values?

The `boolean r` values are "Tai", "John", 1999, 2000, 2001, and 2002.

I must use `.equals();` and I cannot use any other alternative.

**Java**

```
public class example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

   //boolean values are "Tai", "John", 1999, 2000, 2001, and 2002.
   boolean r = false;

   String name = "Tai";

   int year = 1999;
   
   //Boolean gets true if name.equals() values matches boolean values.  
   boolean r = name.equals(year and "Tai");


  }
}
```

For reference, here is a link of something similar I want to achieve but in Java with `.equals();`:

[Boolean Variables and If statement fails for true statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643638/boolean-variables-and-if-statement-fails-for-true-statements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Java logical and is `&&`

So you write:

```
boolean r = name.equals("Tai") && year == 1999;
```

Note that primitives in java compares through `==`, while objects through `.equals()`

Comment: Is there a way to not use `&&` for the answer you provided?

Comment: There are other ways to get the same thing without using `&&`, but they're unnecessarily more complex.  Why don't you want to use `&&`?

Comment: Also if String compare should be case insensitive you write name.equalsIgnoreCase();

Answer (score 0):

If you must use `.equals()` to match an integer and a string then, convert the `int` to `String` using `String.valueOf(int)`. Example :

```
public class example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

   boolean r = false;
   String name = "Tai";
   int year = 1999;
   
   r = name.equals(String.valueOf(year));
  }
}
```